# Ignore certain lines in files when running git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

Let's say I want to compare two log files for differences (not my real use-case but good to point out the problem), but because they have timestamps at the beginning, and those will obviously differ, they'll show every line as different.

Let's consider this (silly) example:

```
00:00:05 something1     00:00:06 something1
00:00:06 something2     00:00:07 something2
00:00:07 something__3   00:00:08 something__4
00:00:08 something5     00:00:09 something5
```

Here we have 2 logs side by side, and the timespamps differ in every line, but only line 3 differs in content - `something3` vs `something4`.

What I do now is that I use Notepad++ to erase the timestamps before diff-ing them, but that's a lot of manual work, esp. for many files. I'd rather if I could just tell `git diff` to first apply a filter to the files before diff-ing them.

Is that possible? I saw this question here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/how-to-diff-files-ignoring-comments-lines-starting-with, where they talk about `diff -u -I '#.*' test{1,2}` but git diff doesn't recognize an `-I` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the two revisions are `commit1` and `commit2`, the file path in the repository is `foo/bar.log`.

```
git diff -U0 \
$(git cat-file -p commit1:foo/bar.log | awk '{$1=""}1' | awk '{$1=$1}1' | git hash-object --stdin -w) \
$(git cat-file -p commit2:foo/bar.log | awk '{$1=""}1' | awk '{$1=$1}1' | git hash-object --stdin -w)
```

`git cat-file -p commit1:foo/bar.log` prints the content of the file of one revision. `awk` removes the first field, the timestamp. `git hash-object --stdin -w` creates a blob. `git diff` compares the two blobs. `-U0` removes the context from the output.

The two blobs are dangling. You could run `git gc --prune=now` to remove them. You could also leave them alone as they will be wiped out in a few days.

A sample function in `~/.bashrc`:

```
function difflog() {
    local left=$1
    local right=$2
    local path=$3
    git diff -U0 \
        $(git cat-file -p ${left}:${path} | awk '{$1=""}1' | awk '{$1=$1}1' | git hash-object --stdin -w) \
        $(git cat-file -p ${right}:${path} | awk '{$1=""}1' | awk '{$1=$1}1' | git hash-object --stdin -w)
    git gc --prune=now --quiet
}
```

To call the function, `difflog HEAD HEAD~1 foo/bar`.

Comment: I wonder if this could be made into a .bashrc function. We could replace the commits with `HEAD` and `HEAD~1`, or we could just compare the working folder file to `HEAD`.

Comment: @sashoalm updated the answer. You could define the function name and parameters.